# sample() function in R

Tags: r, simulate, probability-density

My question is quite simple, I'm trying to simulate 500 draws from any distribution using `sample()`.

Let's take binomial distribution B(10,0.5) for example. Using the `sample()` function in R.

This is what I did:

```
draw = 1:500
data = sample(x=draw, size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(0.5, each=500))
```

However whenever I draw the historgram, it looks like it's random and doesn't have a binomial distribution. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I know there is `rbinom()` function in r that does this. I am trying to understand how the `sample()` function works.

Comment: You probably want to look at `?rbinom`.

Comment: I know rbinom works. is there a way to do this with sample? I want to understand how this function works exactly. It's not always behaving how I expect it to. Let me modify the question.

Comment: The fact that your `data` result is not binary should be your first clue that something is not right. Change the input data to draw from to binary and see what happens.

Comment: Where you are putting 'draw' is where sample expects a bag of values from which to draw. The  size argument should be the number of draws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample(x = c(1,0),size = 10,replace=TRUE,prob = c(0.5,0.5))
```

You may want to histogram the sum of this vector generated multiple times to see your binomial distribution.

```
draws=c()
for(i in 1:500){
  draws=c(draws,sum(sample(x = c(1,0),size = 10,replace=TRUE,prob = c(0.5,0.5))))
}
hist(draws)
```

In this example `sample` is returning 10 (`size = 10`) samples of the values 1 or 0 (`x = c(1,0)`), with equal probability for each (`prob = c(0.5,0.5)`).  `replace=TRUE` just means that either item can be draw more than once.  These 1's and 0's are the results of 10 bernoulli trials with probability 0.5. The binomial distribution is the probability distribution of the number of successes (1's) in a series of n Bernoulli trials each with probability p. So (n=10 and p=0.5). Calling sample once gives the 10 draws, summing that vector gives a draw from the binomial. We take 500 draws from that binomial distribution and draw a histogram.

Comment: this doesn't give a binomial distribution histogram, nor does it sample 500 times.

Comment: this works. thanks! could u explain to me how this works exactly? what would sample return? A value between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 3):

```
data = rbinom(n=500,size=10,prob=.5)
hist(data)
```

Comment: this works. But I'm trying to understand how sample() works. Is there a way to replicate this using sample()?

Comment: @BKS Looks like you accepted another answer using only `sample` but you could also do something like this: `data <- rbinom(n=500,size=10,prob=.5);
samp <- sample(data, 50, replace = T)`

Comment: could also do something like this: `while(TRUE){if(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),1)){hist(rbinom(500,10,0.5));break}}`