# Generate binomial samples determining the probability

Tags: r, random, statistics

I want to generate n samples of binary values (0 or 1) randomly:

This is easy with runif:

`samples <- round(runif(n,min=0, max=5))`

But the probability of having 0 or 1 is 50%. But, what if I want to state a probability of for example 30% of having 1 and 70% of having 0?

I thank you a lot

Comment: Then you just sample from the binomial distribution, i.e., use `rbinom`. You should do that also in the case of equal probabilities.

Comment: If you just have two values then you could use `samples <- as.numeric(runif(n)<.3)`. For more complicated situations try the `sample` function: `samples <- sample(0:1, n, replace=T, prob=c(.3, .7))`

Comment: `rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=.3)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sample() function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691089/sample-function-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sample from the binomial distribution, use `rbinom`:

```
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility
#the sample:
res <- rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = 0.3)

#check probabilities
mean(res)
#[1] 0.293
```